# What is "batching" in context of Git steps to commit

Tags: git

Going through the O'Reilly book on Git and in one of the opening chapters, the author explains how the `add`  command only stages a file, "an interim step before committal".

I do not understand fully the following sentence:
"Git separates the `add` and `commit` steps to avoid volatility. Imagine how disruptive, confusing, and time-consuming it would be to update the repository each time you add, remove, or change a file. Instead, multiple provisional and related steps, such as an add can be batched, keeping the repository in a stable, consistent state".

I guess I am just not sure on how you would actually do this batching, or even keep track of such batching, when you are dealing with multiple files in a project especially. How are you keeping track of which ones you have merely added, and which ones you have actually committed?

Comment: I've never heard the term "batching" officially used with Git, but all it seems to mean here is that you build up a number of local commits, without actually hitting the server each time you do something.

Comment: How would you see this buildup of local commits then? Once you call git add, the file is in the repository but it is in a state of being staged rather than committed. Is that corect?

Comment: Actually just typing `git status` will tell you how far ahead/behind your local branch is with respect to the remote.  I think the point about your question here is just that Git is designed to be loosely coupled to the remote server.  In addition to performance, this also means that there is a lot you can do locally "offline" from the server.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the claim *the add command only stages a file, "an interim step before committal", and does not deposit it into the repository* is technically false: `git add` copies a file from the work-tree to the index, and that copy technically occurs by turning the file into a Git object (called a *blob*). Git then stores the hash ID of the blob in the *index*, which is also called the *staging area* and the *cache*. But that's not a detail meant for an introduction. :-)

Comment: My paraphrasing there and I probably do not have a correct interpretation of what it means to deposit a file into a repository. I checked back over it now that I have a better understanding of it, and he does say you use git add to add a file to the repository.

Comment: Actually in retrospect, the author’s use of “such as” in context of “such as an add” clarifies the intent behind the meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How are you keeping track of which ones you have merely added

the command [git status](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) tells you which files you have added. The files listed from that command will be committed to the repo if you immediately execute a [git commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)

> and which ones you have actually committed?

[git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) tells you which commits have been performed and the order in which they apply. To determine which files have been changed for a particular commit, use [git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

For a specific commit `123456`, I would execute:

`git diff 123456^! --name-status`

to get a file listing, and then:

`git diff 123456^! path/to/file.txt`

for the specific file diff.